# Copy Block of Data with Blanks to Other Location

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste

I'm reusing this string from another thread to copy a whole column WITH the blanks (needed for alignment of other information) to a new location.  BUT I see that its copy action will stop at the first blank AND infact it does.  What I need it to do is copy the blanks and everything as a block then put it under the Range as below.  I considered filling all the blanks first but that just sends the fill value all the way to infinity. There will be more blanks than data.

```
Range(Range("P2"), Range("P2").End(xlDown)).Copy  '!!!Stops at frist blank!!!
For idx = 1 To 1

Columns("P:P").Cut
    Cells(Range("D2").End(xlDown).Row + 1, "D").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
Next
```

I'm not seeing why it can't do that.  I don't need it to be THIS code if there is some other solution.  The task is that I'm changing the layout from one associated information fills a complete row to a "stacked" layout, where associated data (with some blanks) repeats down the column.  So the segments are to be stacked.  Cut copy pate with the whole columns has been mostly working.

It could copy a range based on the non empty value of another cell prior to moving it.  BUT it needs to land on the first empty cell at the bottom of the new range.  I'll repeat this for several columns but can do it separately.

I could bypass the first issue if I with some code that would look at the cells in columns BI through BO and fill them with a value ("0" or "-") IF the value in BH is NOT blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code and question is a little bit confusing but I think this is what you're looking for.  this should copy all data from column P including blanks.

```
Range(Range("P2"), Range("P" & ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row)).Copy
```

Comment: Which can be shortened down to: Range("P2", Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row).Copy